# Percentages in calculation

Tags: c++

I wrote this code:

```
std::cout << "When did you graduate? "; 
int graduation_year = 0;
std::cin >> graduation_year;
std::cout << "\n"; 
std::cout << "How much is your student debt? ";
double debt = 0;
std::cin >> debt;

std::cout << "You graduated in " << graduation_year << " and have student debt worth " << debt << ".\n";

double discount = 0;

switch (graduation_year) {
case 2010:
{
    if (debt >= 5000 && debt < 10000)
        double discount = .99;
    double payment = debt * discount;
    std::cout << "Your student debt is between 5000 and 10000 which means your payment would be " << payment << "\n";
}
break;
```

This is not for a school assignment, I'm simply trying to learn C++ and trying to get the hang of percentages and switch/case.

Annoyingly, when I change this part

```
    double discount = .99;
double payment = debt * discount;
```

to

```
double payment = debt * 0.99;
```

it works perfectly. So I feel like something might be going wrong because of the double being <1, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is. The code continues with case 2011 etc, but it gives the exact same problems for that part of the code so I figured I'd leave that out.

Answer (score 12):

You are re-declaring *discount* as an internal variable to the block of the following *if-statement*

```
if (debt >= 5000 && debt < 10000)
    double discount = .99;
```

You should write it like this:

```
if (debt >= 5000 && debt < 10000)
    discount = .99;
```

---

**ETA:** a bit of explanation.

The *discount* declaration within the *if-block* temporarily hides the **global** *discount* declaration. Although the value is correctly assigned to the inner *discount* declaration, when you get out of the *if-block* this variable is **out of scope**, and any further reference to *discount* is resolved using the **global** *discount* declaration. Since you didn't change the *global* variable, you don't get the right result.

Comment: Jesus, I knew it had to be something stupid on my part. Thanks a lot man, you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @tobi303, I declared discount as double earlier, above the switch part :)